# C: Token system tokenize, but doing if statements fail

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, scripting, token

I have this little function, that is suppose to parse tokens.

```c
void LWDL_Parse(LWDL_Data data, LWDL_State state) {
  char ch;
  LWDL_string contents = "lwdl_data\n";
  LWDL_Array tokens;
  LWDL_TOOL_INIT_ARRAY( & tokens, 5); // 5 is starting size. 

  while ((ch = fgetc(state.LWDL_File)) != EOF) {

    contents = LWDL_TOOL_AppendCharacters(contents, ch);

  }
  LWDL_string chunks;
  const char remove[4] = "   \n";
  chunks = strtok(contents, remove);
  while (chunks != NULL) {
    chunks = strtok(NULL, remove);

    if (chunks != NULL){
    LWDL_TOOL_INSERT_ARRAY( & tokens, chunks);
    }

   
  }

    LWDL_TOOL_FREE_ARRAY(&tokens);
}
```

but doing if statements with the tokens array or the chunks, fail.

```
if (tokens.array[0] == "token"){
       printf("works!\n");
}
```

any clue on how to fix this. If I do a for loop on all elements, they all get parsed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use a compare function like `strcmp` instead of `tokens.array[0] == "token"`

Answer (score 0):

I expect this:

```
if (chunks != NULL){
LWDL_TOOL_INSERT_ARRAY( & tokens, chunks);
}
```

should be before the second call to `strtok()`

otherwise the first token is being ignored